# python pandas showing error while compiling

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i am new to python and i am using pandas for the first time. i saw a post in http://pastebin.com/VxeUT5zW and tried to implement that. i am using python 3.4 and have installed all the necessary packages. but i am getting some errors. i tried to correct it by myself,checked internet and all.. but i couldnt rectify it. please help me to correct it.

```
 # coding=utf-8
# Linear Regression Realization (http://dataaspirant.com/2014/12/20/linear-      regression-implementation-in-python/)

# input_data.csv:
# square_feet;price
# 150;6450
# 200;7450
# 250;8450
# 300;9450
# 350;11450
# 400;15450
# 600;18450

# Required Packages
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import pandas as pd
 from sklearn import linear_model


# Function to get data
def get_data(file_name):
data = pd.read_csv('C:\Python34\data\input_data.csv', sep=";")
x_parameter = []
y_parameter = []
# TODO: Replace the names of the fields 'square foot', 'price' for your own       values
for single_square_feet in data['square_feet']:
    x_parameter.append([float(single_square_feet)])

for single_price_value in data['price']:
    y_parameter.append(float(single_price_value))
return x_parameter, y_parameter


 # Function for Fitting our data to Linear model
    # noinspection PyPep8Naming
 def linear_model_main(x_parameters, y_parameters, predict_value):
# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(x_parameters, y_parameters)
# noinspection PyArgumentList
predict_outcome = regr.predict(predict_value)
predictions = {'intercept': regr.intercept_, 'coefficient': regr.coef_,    'predicted_value': predict_outcome}
return predictions


# Function to show the resutls of linear fit model
def show_linear_line(x_parameters, y_parameters):
# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(x_parameters, y_parameters)
plt.scatter(x_parameters, y_parameters, color='blue')
# noinspection PyArgumentList
plt.plot(x_parameters, regr.predict(x_parameters), color='red', linewidth=4)
# Supress axis value
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())
plt.show()


X, Y = get_data('C:\Python34\data\input_data.csv')
predicted_value = 700
result = linear_model_main(X, Y, predicted_value)
print('Constant Value: {0}'.format(result['intercept']))
print('Coefficient: {0}'.format(result['coefficient']))
print('Predicted Value: {0}'.format(result['predicted_value']))
show_linear_line(X, Y)
```

and the error i am getting is:

[Compilation error scrnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9Wtr.png)

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Victor>cd\

```
C:\>Python34\python.exe C:\Python34\data\cp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\data\cp.py", line 60, in <module>
X, Y = get_data('C:\Python34\data\input_data.csv')
File "C:\Python34\data\cp.py", line 22, in get_data
data = pd.read_csv('C:\Python34\data\input_data.csv', sep=";")
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 645, in    parser
_f
 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 400, in _read
data = parser.read()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 938, in read
ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1507, in read
data = self._reader.read(nrows)
File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 846, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read   (pandas\parser.c:10364)
File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 868, in  pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:10640)
File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 922, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:11386)
File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 909, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows(pandas\parser.c:11257)
File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 2018, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas\parser.c:26979)pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 37, saw 2


C:\>
```

please help me
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please copy the error message as text, not as image?

Comment: i have added the error. i am not sure about encoding. i used both notepad and sublime text(other python scripts are working fine)

Comment: It's clearer now., the problem lies with your `input_data.csv` file. You should check the file. There seems to be a problem at line 37.

Comment: i have used the dataset provided by them

Comment: I think you have the wrong separator. That would explain why it expects 1 field only. And then you probably have a `;` in a value somewhere that splits the row in 2.

Comment: yes..that was the error... i saved it using notepad..but opened via excel..so all ; were eliminated..now it is working...